# unexpected '?' in laravel framework illuminate helpers.php line 233

Tags: php, laravel, apache, composer-php

I have two xampp installed in the same drive, one is xampp with PHP 5.6.x, the other is xampp PHP 7.2.0. I already set the ports for xampp with PHP 7, 443 to 444, 80 to 7777 and they both run smoothly. I do some double checks by running phpinfo() in both localhost and localhost:7777 and it seems correct.

I installed laravel 5.5 in xampp PHP 7 and run composer install. I got this error:

> PHP Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in [path to
>   htdocs]/mylaravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on
>   line 233

It's as if the laravel is still running in xampp with PHP 5 while I put it in xampp PHP 7 folder. I can't remove xampp PHP 5 completely because I'm still using it for most of my works. I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233) but I don't understand since I'm not a Linux User.

Does anybody know the solution for this?

**UPDATE**

I execute php -v in command prompt and it displayed:

> PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 19:48:22)

Does this mean that I'm still running PHP 5.6.30? how can I force it to run PHP 7?

Comment: you are probably right it is still using php 5, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708158/7354094 this post explains how to use both php version in one xampp.  hope it helps

Comment: Your composer installation use PHP in version < 7. You should use php 7.x executable with composer.