# Install multiple versions of XAMPP on a mac

Tags: macos, xampp, osx-elcapitan

I want to install multiple XAMPP versions.

In the answer from `NivF007` to the question [how-to-install-multiple-xampp-versions-or-multiple-php-versions-on-mac-os-x-10-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501003/how-to-install-multiple-xampp-versions-or-multiple-php-versions-on-mac-os-x-10-7) it is said

> Install each instance of XAMPP in it's own folder

But **how** can you do this? (Because you can't change the installation directory)

[image: xampp installation directory]

And when you rename the XAMPP folder after installing the manager doesn't work.

Comment: I want try to install it but I afraid it will conflict with my another version xampp

Answer (score 0):

Use the  portable versions, there you can chnage the path:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/

Comment: This might be a good answer if you expand it a bit. For example, by explaining what the portable versions are and how they're different, and by describing the steps for changing the path.

Comment: u just unzip the files in a different directory and you are done

Comment: How do you unzip this file? After mounting the dmg file I see a contained app file and nothing more.