# How can I install multiple xampp on Mac?

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

I using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.1

I want to install two xampp in my Mac (xampp 7.0.27 and xampp 7.1.13)

First, I had install xampp 7.0.27 in my Mac and it works. It's stored in `/Applications/XAMPP`

Second, I try to install xampp 7.1.13 in my Mac. Seems it's failed. Because it's stored in `/Applications/XAMPP` too. Does not seem to be custom the path

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to install two versions of the same application?

Comment: @MartinBean I have two project. The projects using different php version.

Comment: you can install wamp and xampp

Comment: @pedramshabani Why can not I install 2 xampp on mac os? I can install 2 xampp in windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp)

Comment: I did not try this..always i have xampp and wamp ....or you can have Portable xampp...

Comment: The major problem is that apache and mysql need a specific port to bind to. If you change their default ports then there's no reason why you can't have 2 installations of them. You may need to install them manually though

Comment: @Success Man You’d be better off looking at something like Vagrant, where you can have a self-contained environment with separate PHP versions etc for each of your projects.

Comment: @rickdenhaan This is not windows. This is Mac

Comment: @apokryfos You should answer this question in more detail. I have tried it like my question. But it seems it can not

Comment: @MartinBean I'm still confused. You should answer this question in more detail. I need a specific answer

Comment: @pedramshabani Seems wamp is not support Mac OS

Comment: oh i don't know it:-(...and what about  EasyPHP 5.3.9 or Portable xampp

Comment: @pedramshabani Where can I download portable xampp? https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html. Is XAMPP-VM / PHP 7.1.13?

Comment: I search about this.for mac you can not use Portable version.it is posible install xamp on USB stick and then use of USB stick on mac but It's very troublesome.This is easier--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501003/how-to-install-multiple-xampp-versions-or-multiple-php-versions-on-mac-os-x-10-7

Comment: @SuccessMan Principle is the same for Mac or Windows. You can install multiple PHP versions on Mac, then change XAMPP's Apache config to point to a specific version as needed.

Answer (score 9):

A not-so-pretty solution that works:

1. Install the first XAMPP version and then rename
   `/Applications/XAMPP` to something like `/Applications/XAMPP-7.0.27`.
2. After that, install the second XAMPP version and then rename
   `/Applications/XAMPP` to something like
   `/Applications/XAMPP-7.1.13`.

In order to run the preferred version just rename it back to `/Applications/XAMPP` and run the manager-osx.

Comment: This is also how I handle the issue. I also recommend placing the htdocs directory elsewhere on your system, and symlinking from each XAMPP instance. This way you can use the same project code in different environments.

Comment: Then everytime you want to run the xampp server change the folder name back to XAMPP and then the xampp console will work.. save different versions, then run from the original name whichever you want to run

Comment: @majorobot how about the mysql? How to get same db in different environtment?

Comment: @webchun -- that's a downside. They will be different MySQL instances. The different versions of XAMPP have different versions of MySQL, so it's likely not possible/advisable to share dbs between instances. If you're able to set up a db external to XAMPP, I suppose you could use that for all of your XAMPP instances.

Comment: @majorobot I ended up doing the symlink for the physical mysql data folder. It works perfectly just like the htdocs folder ;)

Comment: Good tip, @webchun. May try that myself (after backing up the data first).